# i have written a code ERROR IS Method already defined: void searchbox.(ApexPages.StandardController) from the type searchbox pl

Tags: apex

```
public class searchbox 
{
    public List<SelectOption> options {set;get;}
    public string selected            {set;get;}
    public list<Packages__C> packages {set;get;}
    public Packages__C acc {get; set;}
    public Integer total {get; set;}
   

    public searchbox(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
    {
        List<string> Countries =new List<String>{'USA','Australia','Canada'};
            options =new List<selectoption>();
        SelectOption n =new Selectoption('none','-None-');
        options.add(n);
        
        for(String s:Countries)
        {
            SelectOption op =new SelectOption(s,s);
            
            options.add(op);
        }
      packages =[select Name,Application_Processing__c,VISA_Processing__c,University_Selection__c,coaching__C from packages__C];
    }
    Public void search(){
        if(selected=='none')
        {
            packages =[select Name,Application_Processing__c,VISA_Processing__c,University_Selection__c,coaching__C from packages__C ];
        }
        else
        {
            packages =[select Name,Application_Processing__c,VISA_Processing__c,University_Selection__c,coaching__C from packages__C where Country__c=:selected];
          
        }
        
    }
   
    public searchbox (ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        acc = (Packages__C)controller.getRecord();
        
        if(acc != null && acc.Id != null) 
        {
            acc = [Select Id, Name, Application_Processing__c, University_Selection__c, VISA_Processing__c from Packages__c where Id =: acc.Id];
        }
    }
    
    public PageReference calculate() 
    {
        total = (acc.Application_Processing__c != null ? Integer.valueOf(acc.Application_Processing__c): 0) +
                (acc.University_Selection__c != null ? Integer.valueOf(acc.University_Selection__c): 0) +
                (acc.VISA_Processing__c != null ? Integer.valueOf(acc.VISA_Processing__c): 0);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong. You're defining a method that already exists.

Let's take a look at the outline of your class (that is, just the class-level variables and method signatures)

```java
public class searchbox 
{
    public List<SelectOption> options {set;get;}
    public string selected            {set;get;}
    public list<Packages__C> packages {set;get;}
    public Packages__C acc {get; set;}
    public Integer total {get; set;}

    // first defined constructor
    public searchbox(ApexPages.StandardController)

    Public void search()

    // second defined constructor
    public searchbox(ApexPages.StandardController)
    
    public PageReference calculate()
}
```

I hope this makes it clear that you have two `searchbox()` constructors that take the exact same arguments (a single instance of `ApexPages.StandardController`). That's a syntax error, which is why Salesforce is complaining about it.

You'll either need to remove one of those constructors, or alter the arguments for one of them (add or remove argument(s), they just can't be 100% identical). It's the combination of the method name + the arguments that needs to be unique (if a method has >= 2 arguments, shuffling the order is sufficient to stop Salesforce from complaining)